# Many reads/one write in atomic variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

Could you help me please.

Suppose I have p - 1 read threads and one write thread. They all read and write in one atomic int variable. Could it be that if all reads and write occur simultaneously the write operation will wait p - 1 time? I have doubts because when atomic operation happens there is some strange lock(in assembler) and I afraid that it locks memory(where variable is). So it could happen that write operation will wait for p-1 reads. Could it happen?

Here is some simple code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>


std::atomic<int> val;

void writer()
{
    val.store(7);
}

void read()
{
    int tmp = val.load();

    while (tmp == 0)
    {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": wait" << std::endl;
        tmp = val.load();
    }

    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Operation: " << tmp * tmp << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    val.store(0);

    std::vector<std::thread> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
        v.push_back(std::thread(read));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(77));

    writer();

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what really *atomic* does, but there's a good chance, that it is: 1. lock 2. access 3. unlock. So if you want to *prioritize* access, *atomic* is too simple for it. You should set up a bit more sophisticated locking construction. There should be the "write request" flag 1. Upon write, set it before modifying the value, modify the value, then clear it. 2. Upon read, don't touch the variable until this flag is set. Result: when a read access arrives, it will suspend until write finishes.

Comment: But the same problem arises. When I will set flag upon write it may wait for some read accesses will end. And I'm afraid of that wait time(of write thread) proportional to the number of read accesses.

Comment: I have another idea: double-buffering. There are two values, A and B. There is an *index* variable, which points to the actual value, it can be A or B. Read threads are reading from the actual value, described by *index*. Write does the trick: it writes value to *1 - index*, then swaps, *index := 1 - index*. So, there will be no any read "queued" before write. You have to use a common lock for reading A and B avoid order issue when swapping (avoid: some read-A hangs at lock-A, so arriving read-B finishes sooner with new value, because no one hangs on lock-B). With one lock, read order is OK.

Answer (score 3):

1. Processor's *instruction*, which locks memory bus(has LOCK prefix), does not use locking in usual, high-level sence. It makes threads(caller one and, probably, some concurrent threads which access same or near memory blocks) **a bit slower**.
   The upper limit of this **bit** is only depends from machine and its architecture.
   Normal locks also make threads slower, but amount of this slowerness **highly  depends** from lock contention, locking implementation properties(e.g., fairness), and code under lock protection. *You shouldn't bother about locked memory access except because of perfomance reason*.
2. Actually, LOCK prefix doesn't need for atomic loads/stores. I guess, it is a compiler optimization, which provides sequential consistent memory order. This order is enforced by `.store()` and `.load()` atomic's methods by default, but it is unnecessary in your example. The mostly used pattern is:

   - use *relaxed* memory order for initialization:

     ```
     val.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
     ```
   - use *acquire* memory order for read value:

     ```
     tmp = val.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
     ```
   - use *release* memory order for write(change) value:

     ```
     val.store(7, std::memory_order_release);
     ```

   This will prevent compiler from using instructions with LOCK prefix.